# sorting listbox in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I'm using listbox in c# as a container to a user-defined objects.
how can I sort the list by a class member (int) of the objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = list.OrderBy(item => item.NumberValue).ToList();
```

**[Edit]**

This is given that the list you hade is named list, you've included the System.Linq namespace, and that the numeric property you were talking about is named NumberValue.